# R One sample test for set of columns for each row

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I have a data set where I have the Levels and Trends for say 50 cities for 3 scenarios. Below is the sample data -

```
City <- paste0("City",1:50)

L1 <- sample(100:500,50,replace = T)
L2 <- sample(100:500,50,replace = T)
L3 <- sample(100:500,50,replace = T)

T1 <- runif(50,0,3)
T2 <- runif(50,0,3)
T3 <- runif(50,0,3)

df <- data.frame(City,L1,L2,L3,T1,T2,T3)
```

Now, across the 3 scenarios I find the minimum Level and Minimum Trend using the below code -

```
df$L_min <- apply(df[,2:4],1,min)
df$T_min <- apply(df[,5:7],1,min)
```

Now I want to check if these minimum values are significantly different between the levels and trends respectively. So check **L_min** with columns 2-4 and **T_min** with columns 5-7. This needs to be done for each **city (row)** and if significant then return which column it is significantly different with.

It would help if some one could guide how this can be done.

Thank you!!

Comment: So you want to find statistically significant comparisons such as value from row 1 column L1 and L_min? 1 vs 1?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what do you mean by, "Significantly different"?

Comment: @Adamm, Thank you for looking at this. I want to check if L_min is significantly different from L1 & L2 & L3 for each row (City). Similarly if T_min is significantly different from T1 & T2 & T3. Once I have this then since L_min and T_min are minimum values from the 3 scenarios then want to understand in how many cases the minimum value is significantly different for each of the 3 scenarios and conclude which scenario is better.

Comment: @Enigma, By Significantly different I am referring to significance testing. In this case I believe it would be one sample t test

Comment: And what statistical test do you propose? As I see in tags - ANOVA, hmm. Data sets are pretty small. For example Let's take row 44 and use simple wilcox.test: `A <- c(480, 420, 118)` , `B <- c(118)` , `wilcox.test(A,B)`. The p-value is 0.6374. I think that you won't get any statistically significant comparsions in your data set, unless you know some sophisticated statistical test for data sets such like these. If I were you I'd make typical fold change and log fold change calculation and set threshold to 1 or 1.5.

Comment: @user1412 Looking at the explanation given in the comment, I feel it's open to interpretation. You can't compare L_min with L1, L2, L3 separately since as Adam noted it'll be 1 vs 1. If you want to compare min values of "Levels" and "Trends" separately using One sample t test (as you mentioned) with rest of values in the rows serving as sample points, something like `Levels<-apply(df[,2:4], 1, function (x) t.test(x, mu=min(x)))` and `Trends<-apply(df[,5:7], 1, function (x) t.test(x, mu=min(x)))` would help.

Comment: @Enigma, Thank you. I understand your point on comparing L_min with L1,L2,L3...I used the code using the apply function and extracted the p-values.....As mentioned by Adamm, I am not getting any significant values. I am not able to conclude which scenario is working better than the other. Is there any other test that I can do to check the significance of the 3 scenarios and conclude which is better?

Comment: @Adamm, As you mentioned I am not getting any significant value after doing one sample t test. Could you please suggest what else i can do to conclude which scenario is better out of the 3. What you mean by typical fold change and log fold change?

Comment: Enigma's idea is good, however p-value never will be less than 0.05 unless you decide to set p-value treshold for 0.2 for example but I won't recommend that.. Therefore I'd like to propose something like this: `df$FC <- rowMeans(df[,2:4])/df[,8]` each value greater than 1.5 is an significantly different. Here is explanation https://www.biostars.org/p/101727/

Comment: @Adamm, Thank you for your suggestion. Could yo please confirm the logic behind 1.5? So if I understand correctly we are taking the average and dividing by the minimum and saying if the result is greater than 1.5 then it is significant. Why 1.5 only? Sorry may be I am missing something basic but it would help if you could confirm.

Comment: In context of gene expression we take treshold of 2. And that means that expression of genes from sample 1 are 2 times bigger than gene expression in sample 2, hence this is interesting for us. Of course FC value may vary from huge numbers because it's simply division. So we perfom logaritmic normalization and no matter of how FC we have logFC between for example between -5 and 5.

Comment: @Adamm, Sorry but your last comment went bouncer to me....I wanted to understand why > 1.5 and not > 1.25 OR > 1.75 etc. I searched for gene expression on google and it talks about protein / DNA etc. Requesting you to please explain in very simple words as this concept is new to me. OR you could point me to some material on this concept. Sorry for taking your time but I hope you would understand.....

Comment: This isn't arbitrarily fixed value such as p-value. If greater FC than difference of 'min' value to other Levels will be bigger. Let's take row with highest FC(2.355769): `104,210,421` and with the lowest one FC(1.040201):  `199,221,201`. Now you see than min from 1st exaple is different a lot in comparison to other two, in contrast to 2nd example.

Comment: @Adamm, Thank you !! This helps. I understand that by 1.5 in a way we are saying that the minimum value is less by atleast 50%, right?

Comment: In 1st case that I mentoned we have FC = 2.35, that means your minimum values is 135% less than average from all 3 values. If FC is equal or close to 1 that means, the difference is very small. Therefore if I were you I'd set FC threshold to >1.5, so we know that minimum value is 50%(or more) smaller than average of all three - columns 2:4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll put my idea here, nevertheless I'm looking forward for ideas for others.

```
> head(df)
  City  L1  L2  L3       T1         T2        T3 L_min      T_min
1 City1 251 176 263 1.162313 0.07196579 2.0925715   176 0.07196579
2 City2 385 406 264 0.353124 0.66089524 2.5613980   264 0.35312402
3 City3 437 333 426 2.625795 1.43547766 1.7667891   333 1.43547766
4 City4 431 405 493 2.042905 0.93041254 1.3872058   405 0.93041254
5 City5 101 429 100 1.731004 2.89794314 0.3535423   100 0.35354230
6 City6 374 394 465 1.854794 0.57909775 2.7485841   374 0.57909775
> df$FC <- rowMeans(df[,2:4])/df[,8]
> df <- df[order(-df$FC), ]
> head(df)
  City  L1  L2  L3        T1        T2         T3 L_min      T_min       FC
18 City18 461 425 117 2.7786757 2.6577894 0.75974121   117 0.75974121 2.857550
38 City38 370 117 445 0.1103141 2.6890014 2.26174542   117 0.11031411 2.655271
44 City44 101 473 222 1.2754675 0.8667007 0.04057544   101 0.04057544 2.627063
10 City10 459 361 132 0.1529519 2.4678493 2.23373484   132 0.15295194 2.404040
16 City16 232 393 110 0.8628494 1.3995549 1.01689217   110 0.86284938 2.227273
15 City15 499 475 182 0.3679611 0.2519497 2.82647041   182 0.25194969 2.117216
```

Now you have the most different rows based on columns 2:4 at the top. Columns 5:7 in analogous way.

And some tips for stastical tests:

1. Always use t.test(parametrical, based on mean) instead of wilcoxon(u-mann whitney - non-parametrical, based on median), it has more power; **HOWEVER**:

-Data sets should be big ex. hipotesis: Montreal has taller citizens than Quebec; t.test will work fine when you take a 100 people from each city, so we have height measurment of 200 people 100 vs 100.

-Distribution should be close to normal distribution in all samples; or both samples should have similar distribution far from normal - it may be binominal. Anyway we can't use this test when one sample has normal distribution, and second hasn't.

-Size of both samples should be eqal, so 100 vs 100 is ok, but 87 vs 234 not exactly, p-value will be below 0.05, however it may be misrepresented.

If your data doesn't meet above conditions, I prefer non-parametrical test, less power but more resistant.

Comment: Thank you very much!! This was the closet answer to my requirement.